# Autopopulate one sheet when "Yes" is entered in a cell in another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I don't know a lot about VBA or excel - so looking for lots of help!! :)

I currently have a page set up like Picture 1. I would be typing "Yes" or "No" into the the yellow boxes. Upon entering yes, I would like the certain rows and columns to auto-populate the other sheet as shown in Picture 2.

Thanks

Picture 1:
[image: Picture 1]

Picture 2:
[image: Picture 2]

Comment: What have you tried so far and where is the problem?

Comment: I have not tried anything lol. I wasn't sure how you build out the code and was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction or get me started

Comment: You may want to take the time to [read this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: here's a point in the right direction: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office

Answer (score -1):

I am attaching the step by step pictures of the formulae you can use.

I know they are a lot, but I have been using this to create lists based on a criteria. I don't know if anything easier exists. But this one surely works. 
First Picture is Sheet 1,

And the rest is work on sheet 2.

[image: Step 1- Table from where you want to gather data from]

[image: Step 2 - use index function to list tasks in one column]

[image: Step 3 - Use VLOOKUP for listing your adjacent columns as required]

[image: VLOOKUP for another column]

write the formulae as per your requirement, and after you are done writing press Control+Enter (for the INDEX formula) and then drag down.

VLOOKUP works with just Enter and then drag down.